# ArcGIS Pro: where does arcpy reference map order?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, maps, arcgis-notebook

**Problem:** In an ArcGIS Pro 2.8 Notebook, how is python reading the map order? I have to know this because when I use a list the items in that list are based off the order of the maps. When that order is off it's affecting the results.

In Pro, I have 8 maps open ordered from left to right: *Tot Pop, 12-18, 0-18, 11-14, 14-16, 16-18, 19-64, 65+*

[image]

The Catalog *Maps* folder doesn't follow that order. It's ordered from top to bottom as such: *0-18, 11-14, 12-18, 14-16, 16-18, 19-64, 65+, Tot Pop*

[image]

Python prints a different order. I thought it was ordering based on the open maps, but that doesn't seem to be consistent behavior. When I run this the map order is different from both of the above.

```py
import arcpy
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject('CURRENT')
for map in aprx.listMaps():
    print(map.name)
```

```
prints:

Tot Pop
11-14
0-18
12-18
14-16
16-18
19-64
65+
```

Comment: I could only guess that there is an internal reference in the project which is being read from. However, I dont think you'll find an authoritative/documented answer to this question short of the arcpy/project/listmaps developer providing feedback. I think you're better to look at methods to sort your list, although I'm not clear as to why you need this list to be in a certain order.

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently looking into that. The reason they need to be in that order is because I'm creating a script that is to be used as a script tool in a colleague's model. I'm retaining the order of the maps as they were ordered when the project was given to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.APRX` is a essentially a zipped up file of .XML documents which keep all the configuration settings for the project.

If you extract the file using 7z you'll see the master file, **GISProject.xml**. You'll also see a 1-many number of directories called **Map#** with **Map#.xml** inside. The GISProject file is a pointer to these Map directories/XML by name (again, that name is the simple Map1, Map2, Map3). These files are numbered based on *the order they were originally created*. The name of these maps you see in Pro or from `listMaps()` comes from the Map#.xml file, which the pointer from the GISProject.xml holds.

Based on this -- `listMaps()` is returning the order the maps were created (Map1, Map2, Map3). It does not list the maps based on their name, the order they appear when opened or as they appear in the Catalog Window > Maps.

You can try to do a sort on the name, although I'm not sure it'll give you exactly what you're after.

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mapNames = [m.name for m in p.listMaps()]
sorted(mapNames)
>> ['0-11', '12-90', 'Top 100']
```

vs

```
p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
for m in p.listMaps(): print(m.name)
>> Top 100
>> 0-11
>> 12-90
```

Disclaimer: These are mostly assumptions based on peeking under the hood. They could be wrong.

Comment: You answered my actual question so I marked your answer as correct. Secondarily, I didn't think ```sorted()``` could work as the map names, being both numbers and letters, didn't lend themselves to the randomness of the project. So, I ended up defining a list of map names in the order I wanted, loop through maps from ```listMaps()```, check if map name is there, if it is get the index of it, replace the item at that index with the map object associated with that name, then return the list in a ```finalList``` variable. --compliments of an ESRI analyst.